# Trouble Sort Google CodeJam 2018 Qualifiers

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to improve my programming skills by solving couple of Code Jam questions. I have been stuck for a while on the "Trouble Sort" question from the Qualifier Rounds in 2018. My code produces the expected output with the example input in my console, but the online judge return "Wrong Answer".

Apparently Trouble sort is just like bubble sort, except instead of comparing the ith and i+1th elements, it compares the ith and i+2th elements and if the former is greater than the latter then the elements are swapped. The question says that this algorithm is flawed as arrays like 897 after trouble sort will return 798, which isn't sorted either. The task is to check if for a given list of integers, trouble sort is able to successfully sort the array or if it isn't then which is the index value of the first element that is out of place.

My code inputs the number of tests t and the size of integer list. Then I make a copy of it and put one copy through bubble sort and the other through trouble sort. Then I compare them element wise and if an index which has the two elements as different integers is found, it is outputted. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;

    void swapVal(int& a, int& b)
    {
        int t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int t;
        cin >> t;
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
        {
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            vector<int> bs(n);
            vector<int> ts(n);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                cin >> bs[i];
                ts[i] = bs[i];
            }

            //bubbleSort(bs, n);

            {
                bool bsSorted = false;
                while (!bsSorted)
                {
                    bsSorted = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (bs[i] > bs[i + 1])
                        {
                            swapVal(bs[i], bs[i + 1]);
                            bsSorted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //troubleSort(ts, n);
            {
                bool tsSorted = false;
                while (!tsSorted)
                {
                    tsSorted = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
                    {
                        if (ts[i] > ts[i + 2])
                        {
                            swapVal(ts[i], ts[i + 2]);
                            tsSorted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            bool same = true;
            int minidx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (bs[i] != ts[i])
                {
                    same = false;
                    minidx = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (same == true)
            {
                cout << "Case #" << i << ": OK" << endl;
            }
            else if (same == false)
            {
                cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << minidx;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am expecting the judge to give me a tick of approval, but instead it is repeatedly returning "Wrong Answer". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post all the relevant information here. Clearly state your problem - don't expect anyone to go searching what is "Trouble Sort" so they can help you. Create proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry @Quimby, I'm new to Stack Overflow. I have made the changes as you have indicated and hope that's enough information. Thanks a lot for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm looks correct to me. I noticed that in the false case you seem to be missing the newline. So two consecutive false statements will be on the same line.

`cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << minidx<<'\n';`

Might solve your problem.

Few remarks:

- `if (same == true)` is equivalent to `if(same)` and `if (same == false)` to `if(!same)`.
- There's already `std::swap`.
- Some people might not like nested for loops having equally named variables - the nested variable will hide the outer one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quimby! Adding the endl at the end of the false condition allowed my program to pass through the first test set, but it said "Time Limit Exceeded" for the second test set. Here's the link in case you want to try it out: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/00000000000000cb/00000000000079cb . And thanks a lot for the pointers. Baby steps right ? :D

Comment: @dhruvkapur_17 No problem, you can accept my answer if you want.